# Kommasetzung in spezifischem Fall - 'dort, aber anderweitig'

Tags: grammaticality, comma

Ich habe den Satz und die nähere Umgebung inzwischen umformuliert, daher brauche ich keine Vorschläge für grundsätzlich andere Herangehensweisen - es geht mir nur darum meine Neugier bezüglich dieser Formulierung zu befriedigen:

> Er schließt ebenfalls neuere Artikel aus, das heißt dort, aber anderweitig nicht, erwähnte Hugos bleiben unberücksichtigt.

'Er' ist der Autor einer Literaturrecherche. Es geht um (Zeitungs-)Artikel, genauer um eine Suche über einen Korpus von Artikeln; Ich bespreche die Auswahl nach Kriterien, und bemängele, dass Hugos die nur in neueren Artikeln erwähnt werden, aber nicht in älteren, unberücksichtigt bleiben. Meine Unsicherheit ist die Kommasetzung.

Hinter 'dort' oder gar nicht? Vor oder hinter 'erwähnte'?

Falls die Grammatik order Rechtschreibung anderweitig nicht passt, gerne einen Kommentar, aber ich brauche, wie gesagt, keine Tipps zur Umsetzung, mich interessiert die Kommasetzung in diesem spezifischen Fall.

Falls die Konstruktion einen Namen hat, gerne kommentieren; dann füge ich das noch ein damit die Frage weniger hyperspezifisch wird.

Comment: Ich verstehe den ganzen Satz nicht, auch nicht nach Björn Friedrichs Zeichensetzung. "... dort erwähnte Hugos, aber anderweitig nicht erwähnte Hugos, bleiben unerwähnt" - geht es um Hugos, die Mehrzahl von Hugo? Wie in Victor Hugo?

Comment: @userunknown Der Satz ist unkenntlich gemacht. Praktisch könnte es um mehrere Personen namens Hugo gehen. Hugo ist hier aber nur ein Platzhalter für irgendeine Gruppe: Theorien, Fischsuppenrezepte, Blätter - würde alles funktionieren.

Comment: Dann schreib doch "Dinge, Elemente, Sachen, Ideen" o.ä. und nicht etwas Irritierendes, wie "Hugos", oder ist das in verschiedenen Subkulturen, die mir fremd sind, Usus? Wir wollen doch Sätze kenntlich, nicht unkenntlich machen. Ich vermute Du willst den Ursprung, aus dem der Satz stammt, unkenntlich machen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richtig ist:

> Er schließt ebenfalls neuere Artikel aus, das heißt, dort, aber anderweitig nicht erwähnte *Hugos* bleiben unberücksichtigt.

1. Vor *das heißt* kommt stets ein Komma.
2. Nach *das heißt* kommt ein Komma, sofern wie hier ein Haupt- oder Nebensatz folgt.
3. In der Regel setzt man vor die Konjunktion *aber* ein Komma, vor die Modalpartikel oder das Adverb *aber* jedoch nicht. (Es gibt gewisse Ausnahmen, die hier keine Rolle spielen.)
4. Zwischen *anderweitig nicht erwähnte* gehört kein Komma. Dass *nicht* zu *anderweitig* gehört, wird aus dem Gegensatz *dort, aber anderweitig nicht* klar.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Habe eine Weile darüber gerätselt, warum wohl vor das heißt stets ein Komma kommt, aber im 'Richtig ist' Beispiel kein Komma vor dem heißt zu finden ist :) Stellt sich raus dass mein Auge/Monitor das Schrägstellen von Text nicht auflöst.